# Delete and update an Item that has be searched by ID in android studio, Java and firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I implemented code in Java to retrieve data from the Firebase database by searching with an ID and show it in the form. If I add the id it will show the data correctly.

Successfully retrieved data
[image: Successfully retrieved data]

Data in firebase
[image: Data in firebase]

But when I try to delete or update this data it is always showing as "No data resource". I tried to implement code but it is not working. How can I delete and update a specific data( Searched by ID),

The whole code I have tried..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtID,txtName,txtAdd,txtConNo,txtid;
    Button btnSave,btnShow,btnUpdate,btnDelete;
    DatabaseReference dbRef;
    Student std;

    String searchID;

    private void clearControls(){
        txtID.setText("");
        txtName.setText("");
        txtAdd.setText("");
        txtConNo.setText("");
        txtid.setText("");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtID = findViewById(R.id.EtID);
        txtName = findViewById(R.id.EtName);
        txtAdd = findViewById(R.id.EtAddress);
        txtConNo = findViewById(R.id.EtConNo);
        txtid = findViewById(R.id.search);


        btnSave = findViewById(R.id.BtnSave);
        btnShow = findViewById(R.id.BtnShow);
        btnUpdate = findViewById(R.id.BtnUpdate);
        btnDelete = findViewById(R.id.BtnDelete);

        std = new Student();


    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Student");
                try{
                    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(txtID.getText().toString()))
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter an ID",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(txtName.getText().toString()))
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter a Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtAdd.getText().toString()))
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter an Address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    else {
                        std.setID(txtID.getText().toString().trim());
                        std.setName(txtName.getText().toString().trim());
                        std.setAddress(txtAdd.getText().toString().trim());
                        std.setConNo(txtConNo.getText().toString().trim());

                        dbRef.push().setValue(std);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Saved Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        clearControls();
                    }
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Contact Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchID = txtid.getText().toString().trim();
                DatabaseReference readRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference dref = readRef.child("Student");
                Query query = dref.orderByChild("id").equalTo(searchID);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                txtID.setText((ds.child("id").getValue().toString()));
                                txtName.setText((ds.child("name").getValue().toString()));
                                txtAdd.setText((ds.child("address").getValue().toString()));
                                txtConNo.setText((ds.child("conNo").getValue().toString()));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Source to Display",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatabaseReference updf = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Student");
                updf.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("Student")){
                            try{
                                std.setID(txtID.getText().toString().trim());
                                std.setName(txtName.getText().toString().trim());
                                std.setAddress(txtAdd.getText().toString().trim());
                                std.setConNo(txtConNo.getText().toString().trim());
                                dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Student");
                                dbRef.setValue(std);
                                clearControls();

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data updated successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing to show",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DatabaseReference deldf = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Student");
                deldf.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("Student")){
                                dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Student");
                                dbRef.removeValue();
                                clearControls();

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Deleted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing to show",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the element with `ID001`, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference studentRef = rootRef.child("Student");
Query queryById = studentRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(idToBeRemoved);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
studentRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result of the above code will be the deletion of the element with `ID001`. If you need to update the same element, simply use `updateChildren()`.

Comment: I don't want to specify the id sir. I want a user to search by id and retrieve data from database. then user can update and delete that details of the id he searched. It can be any id in the database.

Comment: In that case, I changed the hardcoded value of `ID001` with `idToBeRemoved`, a variable that can get the exact value that the user is typing, right?

Comment: yes sir. If the use type id as "ID002" it need to update and delete that particular data.

Comment: Exactly, `idToBeRemoved = textView.getText().toString()`, right?

Comment: Yes sir, If I change removeValue() as updateValue() it is showing error?

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. It should be `updateChildren()` instead of `updateValue()`. Does it work using `updateChildren()`?

Comment: It is still showing error sir. It is asking to add <MAP> in the parenthesis

Comment: That's correct. [updateChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) requires an argument of type `Map<String, Object>`. Please check the docs for [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) specific fields.

Comment: can't I do without adding Map

Comment: No, that `Map<String, Object>` object actually represents the data that you want to update.

Comment: query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            HashMap map = new HashMap();
                            map.put("id",txtID);
                            ds.getRef().updateChildren(map);
                            clearControls();
                        }
                    }    Tried to implement like this but not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221960/discussion-between-deepika-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: @Deepika If you there are other/new issues, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.